# How to show the current date of the month in "MaterialDatePicker" in Android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-datepicker, material-components-android, material-components

I've implemented **MaterialDatePicker** for the purpose of the date selection & also done it but in calendar header initially shows the **First date of the current month**

*Example: Today date is **May 30 2020** but in the calendar before select any date i.e initially it shows **May 1 2020**.*

Here is the code & screenshot:

```
 MaterialDatePicker.Builder startDateBuilder;
 MaterialDatePicker startDatePicker;

 startDateBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
 startDateBuilder.setTitleText("Starting date");

 long today = MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds();


 CalendarConstraints.Builder con = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();

 CalendarConstraints.DateValidator dateValidator = DateValidatorPointForward.now();

 con.setValidator(dateValidator); // Previous dates hide

 con.setStart(today); // Calender start from set day of the month

 startDateBuilder.setSelection(today);

 startDateBuilder.setCalendarConstraints(con.build());
 startDateBuilder.setTheme(R.style.MaterialCalendarTheme); // Custom Theme

 startDatePicker = startDateBuilder.build();

 startDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), startDatePicker.toString());
```

[image]

Comment: The code is correct. Which version are you using? There was a [bug](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/778) now fixed.

Comment: I'm using "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02"

Comment: Use 1.2.0-beta01

Comment: Yes, Now It shows the current date of the month. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But It doesn't show the current data it shows yesterday date. In picker and also a header.

Comment: There is another bug in [MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds()](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/882)

Comment: Any alternative solution to get the current data?

Comment: Now I changed  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); long today = calendar.getTimeInMillis(); instand of MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds(). result => Show current date in header but picker shows yesterday date.

Comment: it works for the selected-day but not for the today day circled by default. Try if the latest stable 1.1.0 works. The fix is just merged, may be in the beta02 is fixed. The ugly alternative is adding +1.

Comment: MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds(); is fixed in 1.3.0-alpha01.

Comment: Yes, Now Fixed in that version

Comment: I used         CalendarConstraints.Builder con = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();

        CalendarConstraints.DateValidator dateValidator = DateValidatorPointForward.now();
        con.setValidator(dateValidator); But yesterday date not hide, I used 1.3.0-alpha01 version.

Answer (score 1):

**My code is correct** it was dependencies version problem. Previously I used the old version, Now update the new version, it was working fine.

> com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02

after changing the implementation

> com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-beta01

In beta01 also have some bugs in shows the current date in the header of the calendar and also a picker.

It doesn't show the current date in beta01 version so I changed to the stable version Now it will work.

> com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0